# Ethernet is not working on Ubuntu 18.04 though WIFI is working

Tags: 18.04, dell, ethernet, lan, ubuntu-drivers

Initially I was using ubuntu 14.04 and ethernet was working fine but wifi is not working fine. Then I changed to later Kernel and got Wifi to work but ethernet isn't working.

Then I decided to upgrade my laptop to 18.04 and Wifi is working but ethernet is still not working. When I plug in the ethernet cable, it shows in the network manager icon with the name "Wired Connection 2" but it doesn't connect to it.

Any help is appreciated in this regard.

Comment: In `network/wired` settings, do you see a "Wired Connection" and a "Wired Connection 1"?

Comment: When I open network icon and click on wired, it only allows me to turn ON and OFF the "wired" connection but not display any connection under it. It just shows "hardware" address below the "wired" connection.  However, when I click on the top right network icon, there it shows me "wired connection 2" under the "Ethernet Network".

Comment: In `terminal` type `nm-connection-editor` and locate any Wired Connection profiles and delete them. Then go back to Network/Wired settings, click the + and create a fresh new "Wired Connection", and see how far you get.